# Why will my Python function not pass all the data to the next python function

Tags: python, function

Im running Python 3.8 on a PC with windows 10

Hi All,
I am very new to programming and Python. I did a search here for answers but the two that came up did not seem applicable.

I have a function that connects to an api that returns bus route information.

```
def bus_route(bus_number):
    bus = bus_number
    # Try out retrieving a URL via urllib3
    # Use %s to pass in the Constants and Variables to make up the URL
    url = BASE_URL + '/route/FESX/%s/inbound/1500IM2456B/2020-05-21/19:25/timetable.json?app_id=%s&app_key=%s' \
                     '&edge_geometry=false&stops=ALL' % (bus, APP_ID, API_KEY)

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    # Request our data, and decode the json data returned
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    bus_route_dict = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
    x = 0
    # iterate through our dictionary giving us the bus stop names and their
    # lat and long so we can plot them on a map.
    while x < len(bus_route_dict['stops']):
        print(x)
        for stop in bus_route_dict['stops']:
            bus_stand = stop['stop_name']
            lat = stop['latitude']
            long = stop['longitude']
            print("DEBUG 4: " + bus_stand + " , " + str(lat) + " , " + str(long))
            #map_it(bus_stand, lat, long)
        return bus_stand, lat, long`
```

I receive this information fine

```
DEBUG 4: Highwood Square , 51.91048 , 0.91805
DEBUG 4: Spindle Wood , 51.91156 , 0.91488
DEBUG 4: Victoria Gardens , 51.90953 , 0.91508
DEBUG 4: Pinecroft Gardens , 51.9076 , 0.91769
....
....
DEBUG 4: Tollgate Centre , 51.88453 , 0.83263
DEBUG 4: Sainsburys Store , 51.88616 , 0.82942
DEBUG 0: Returned from  bus_route() Sainsburys Store , 51.88616 , 0.82942
```

"DEBUG4:" is the print messages from my bus_route() function
"DEBUG 0" is from my main() function that has received the return data from my bus_route function

Up to this point it is all fine. the problem occurs when I comment out the return and uncomment my map_it() function.

bus_route() passed the three parameters bus_stand, lat and long into map_it()

```
def map_it(bus_stand, lat, long):
    # Folium mapping
    stop = bus_stand
    latitude = lat
    longitude = long

    while True:
        print("DEBUG 5: " + stop + " , " + str(latitude) + " , " + str(longitude))
```

I was expecting to get the same output as DEBUG 4 but all I actually get is the following.

```
DEBUG 5: Highwood Square , 51.91048 , 0.91805
DEBUG 5: Highwood Square , 51.91048 , 0.91805
DEBUG 5: Highwood Square , 51.91048 , 0.91805
DEBUG 5: Highwood Square , 51.91048 , 0.91805
....
....
....
```

the map_it() function is meant to be able to provide these values so I can map them on a folium map.

Can someone point out my error, please. I have been staring at this for ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your `map_it` function. This results in your first call to `map_it` endlessly outputting the first arguments passed to it.

Remove the line `while True :` and the indent on the following line to remove this loop and you should get the result you expect.